# C# Dynamically filled DropDownList resets on button OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a bit of a DUH moment and need some help. I have a DropDownList control that gets filled with values on page load and a submit button that does further manipulations. However, when the button is clicked DropDownList returns a value of "-1" and not of the selected option. What is wrong here?

Web page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/new/MasterPageA2.master" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Checkout.aspx.cs" Inherits="Common_Checkout" EnableViewState="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="test11"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbillingcountry" required="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="ImageButton1" AlternateText="Proceed" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) {
    PopulateCountry(ddlbillingcountry);
  }
}

private void PopulateCountry(DropDownList Controlname) {
    DatasetTableAdapters.CountryTableAdapter _CountryTableAdapter = new DatasetTableAdapters.CountryTableAdapter();

    Controlname.ClearSelection();
    Controlname.Items.Clear();      

    DataTable _DataTable = _CountryTableAdapter._Eco_Country_Select(); 
    Controlname.DataSource = _DataTable;
    Controlname.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    Controlname.DataValueField = "Country";
    Controlname.DataBind();
    Controlname.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select Country -", ""));
}

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    test11.Text += "<p>clicked " + ddlbillingcountry.SelectedIndex + " - " + ddlbillingcountry.SelectedValue.ToString();

}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am populating the billing country if it is not clear from the name. As for required, take a peek here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Since i don't see an obvious reason for this behaviour and your page inherits from `Common_Checkout` (`Inherits="Common_Checkout"` in page directive), the reason most likely will be found there.

Comment: I think that you have close the viewstate somewhere in the upper level.

Comment: 1) Is viewstate enabled for the drop down ? 2) Are you deleting drop down data ANYWHERE in the code, if yes then see if it's getting executed by mistake? 3) It could be because of some twisted stuff from Update panel, try removing update panel and confirm if things work without it, if they do then at least you would know that update panel is doing something.

Comment: @BeenishKhan 1) Yes, both on the page and controls level. 2) Not as far as I know, all the code is listed above. The breakpoints showed that the value gets cleared as soon as the button is clicked. 3) Removing UpdatePanel has not changed anything. Any other thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the datasource property to the name of a function which returns a dataset.
Try `datasource='<%# PopulateCountry("ddlbillingcountry") %>'` but you will need to change or overload the function to change the argument to a string, remembering to set the datavaluefield and datatextfield.Or you may want to create a separate function and call that with no arguments.

Comment: I updated the code above to include the calls happening inside the PopulateCountry function call. As you can see, it already uses DataBinding.

Comment: @sbay Do you have any code for the dropdownlist's onSelectedIndexChanged event? Can you confirm that the dropdownlist isn't getting re-populated on postback?